# JButton only appears on mouse over?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, paint

[Here](http://pastebin.com/pqc2r8dz) is my code: I took out some stuff that I felt wasn't necessary. I might've took out some brackets too, but I'm just trying to show the content I have.

What happens is, when I run the program, the background image paints (it's a PNG in resources), and only ONE button appears (my PLAY button), which is the first button - it's auto-selected.

I actually have four buttons but I've only included PLAY and INSTRUCTIONS in my code. The other three don't show up unless I mouse over them. I know it's probably something weird with the paint method, but I don't know how to fix it.

If I select a different button and minimize the window then open it again, that selected button is the only one that appears. I have to mouse over to get the other buttons to appear.

I've added `super.paint()` to the paint method too and I get all my buttons but the background is grey. 
I think the problem is `super.paint()` paints all my buttons, and `g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null)` only paints my background and I can't do one without painting over the other.

Sorry if this was a mess. I'm new at Java and I have trouble articulating what I'm trying to say.

```
public class MainMenu extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */

    //variables
    public static Image bg;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainMenu mainFrame = new MainMenu();
        mainFrame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        mainFrame.setResizable(false);
        mainFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        mainFrame.setTitle ("Zumby");
        mainFrame.setLayout(null);

        // Loads the background image and stores in bg object.
        try {
            bg = ImageIO.read(new File("zumby.png"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * Overrides the paint method.
     * MONDAY
     */
     public void paint(Graphics g)
     {
        // Draws the img to the BackgroundPanel.
        System.out.println("paint");
        g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
     }

    /**
     */
    public MainMenu() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 500);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setOpaque(false);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        //create buttons
        JButton btnPlay = new JButton("PLAY");
        btnPlay.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnPlay.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        btnPlay.setFont(font);
        btnPlay.setBorder(border);
        btnPlay.setFocusPainted(false);

        //if "Play" is clicked

        btnPlay.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click) {
                setVisible(false);
                new GamePlay(); //opens up GamePlay window
            }
        });
        btnPlay.setBounds(600, 64, 141, 61);
        contentPane.add(btnPlay);

        JButton btnInstructions = new JButton("INSTRUCTIONS");

        btnInstructions.setBounds(600, 160, 141, 61);
        btnInstructions.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        btnInstructions.setFocusPainted(false);
       // btnInstructions.setEnabled(true);

        contentPane.add(btnInstructions);
        repaint();
        pack(); 
        setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Paste your code HERE (not in a comment, but in your question, using the edit link)

Comment: Try to put validate(); method on your main frame. I think it would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Swing uses a "layering" concept for it's painting...

`paint` calls `paintComponent`, `paintBorder` and `paintChildren`.  By overriding `paint` and failing to call `super.paint`, you've prevented the component from painting it's various layers.

In Swing, it is preferred to use `paintComponent` to provide custom painting, which allows you to paint underneath any other components that might be added to the component.

[image]

```
public class TestPaint01 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestPaint01();
  }

  public TestPaint01() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        try {
          UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TestPane());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

      }
    });
  }

  public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    private Image backgroundImage;

    public TestPane() {
      try {
        BufferedImage background = ImageIO.read(new File("/path/to/image.jpg"));
        //backgroundImage = background.getScaledInstance(-1, background.getHeight() / 4, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        backgroundImage = background;
      } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
      add(new JButton("Hello"));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return backgroundImage == null ? super.getPreferredSize() : new Dimension(backgroundImage.getWidth(this), backgroundImage.getHeight(this));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      int x = (getWidth() - backgroundImage.getWidth(this)) / 2;
      int y = (getHeight() - backgroundImage.getHeight(this)) / 2;
      g.drawImage(backgroundImage, x, y, this);
    }

  }

}
```

You might find [A Closer look at the Paint Mechanism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) informative.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's because you're overriding the paint method. It's better to override repaint, then call super.repaint(); Like this:

```
public void repaint(Graphics g)
        {
             super.repaint(g);
         // Draws the img to the BackgroundPanel.
             System.out.println("paint");
           g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, null);
        }
```

Then the components get redrawn as well.

But if all you want to do is show an image as the background see [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064977/setting-background-images-in-jframe)

Comment: @JessicaW Have you tried the code I added at the bottom of the post?

Comment: I have - it doesn't work. That's what happens when there's no background, but the buttons show up.

Comment: This would draw the image over the content previously painted.  Better to use `paintComponent`

Answer (score 2):

You're overriding `paint()` but don't call `super.paint()`. So the normal painting of the components done by the JFrame's `paint()` method implementation is not executed.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using Swing and `JFrame` the painting mechanism used to override `paintComponent` not `paint` that is usually used with applets or AWT.