# Set an image as background to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am making a small app, but i want to set an image as background at the whole window.  I tried to make this like below but nothing happen. The image is in the folder where the class is so as a path I put only the name...Can you help me please? what can I do?

```
Container c = getContentPane();
  setContentPane(c);
   setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Chrysanthemum.jpg")));
```

Comment: Of course ut won't work,a JLabel is a label not the background.

Comment: how can i put an image as background?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1065014/3226218) should help you out.

Comment: Gadzooks!  How many times does [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jframe+background+image) need to be answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possibility is to add a `BorderLayout` to the JFrame, which should fill the `JFrame` with the `JLabel`, then set the background, adding the `JLabel` to the frame and then add components to it, like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Foo extends JFrame {

    public Foo() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());


JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Untitled.png"));
    add(background);
    background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    background.add(new JButton("foo"));
    setSize(500, 500);
    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
}
}
```

The above works for me, with the `JButton` at the top center of the 500 by 500 `JFrame` with the specified background.

Comment: it does not function...i dont know why

Comment: where should i have the image? I have it in the same folder with class...and I specify only the name...but it doesnt work

Comment: @user3233650 The approach is (mostly) correct, the possible reason it doesn't work is that the location of the image isn't where you think it is...

Comment: @user3233650 ImageIcon(String) expects to find the image relative to the context of the execution of the program. Try using new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("imagename")) instead, for example

Comment: The default layout for `JFrame` is already `BorderLayout`. See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a `JPanel` with a background image, and add it to the `JFrame`. I already have a `BackgroundPanel` class right in one of my projects, and this is the setup I have for it.

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    private BackgroundPanel bgPanel;

    public MyFrame() {
        bgPanel = new BackgroundPanel("Chrysanthemum.jpg");

        setTitle("MyFrame");
        setResizable(false);
        setContentPane(bgPanel);
        pack();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();
    }
}

// -- BackgroundPanel class

public class BackgroundPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Image bg;

    public BackgroundPanel(String path) {
        this(Images.load(path).getImage());
    }

    public BackgroundPanel(Image img) {
        this.bg = img;
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(bg.getWidth(null), bg.getHeight(null)));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (bg != null) g.drawImage(bg, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless you want to the background to be resizable, this is waste of effort. Also, the scaling image in this way doesn't take into consideration the ratio of the original image and doesn't generally produce a nice result - IMHO