# How to Add image?

Tags: java

I am trying to add image in a button this `ImageIcon` is giving me error, I also import `java.awt.Image;`. But still image is not uploading, what can I do now?

```
JButton btnFind = new JButton("Find");
    Image img = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/search.png")).getImage();
    btnFind.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img)); 
    btnFind.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        }
    });
    btnFind.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            try {
                 cDriver.fObjectWithDataCity_V3(textFieldSearch.getText());
                 fDataInTextBoxes();



                } catch (Exception ee) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Thanks , problem resolved. because i don't import import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

Comment: Create a custom component, probably based on JPanel, override the paintComponent method and draw your image within it

Comment: Please do not use comments to ask follow-up questions.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to import

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
```

Comment: can you tell me how to add background image in java gui form

Comment: @AhmedAbbas related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064977/setting-background-images-in-jframe