# Background JSwing Image Loading Oddly

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jlabel

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

I can't seem to figure out how I would add in a background WITH all of my panels showing.

I tried to set the JFrame content pane as a label with an imageicon and the frame does show, it just doesn't show the image like above.

This is the code that I've used.

```
frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/Wallpaper.png")));
```

The second attempt I've used is to ADD (not set) an image into the content pane of the frame. This did not work as shown in the second picture above and it only shows the panels but no background. The code is on the bottom.

```
frame.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/Wallpaper.png")));
```

The third attempt I've tried is to create a subclass of JComponent and Override the paintComponents method then setan object of it as the contentpane. This does not work and instead turns my screen blank.

Here is the code I've used and the class code is in the 1st answer of this link [Setting background images in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064977/setting-background-images-in-jframe?lq=1). The result is the 3rd image of this post.

```
        File img = new File("res/Wallpaper.png");

    BufferedImage myImage;
    try {
        myImage = ImageIO.read(img);
        frame.setContentPane(new ImagePanel(myImage));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The 4th attempt I've tried is adding the picture into the main panel that fills up the screen. This does not work at all and instead breaks the image in half so half of the screen has the image half doesn't.

Here is the code I've used for my 4th attempt. The result is the 4th last image on the top.

```
        BufferedImage myPicture;
    try {
        myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("res/Wallpaper.png"));
        JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture));
        pMain.add(picLabel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm not sure why the JPanels aren't showing up.

I know that in the 1st example when you set the frame as a JLabel it gives it a null layout but that was the only way I could find to DISPLAY the image.

I would like to somehow add the panels ontop of the frame with that background but after reading numerous threads I could not find out how.

If anyone does find out, please post the code and explain if you can. I also have the class get the system class theme that sets it into the theme of what the computer is using. Ex. I am using a windows operating system so it shows it kind of like my operating system.

This thread is not a duplicate. In other threads they only have a frame but in my thread I have several panels that aren't showing for some particular reason.

EDIT: I don't know what's up, I tried to use this thread [Setting background images in JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064977/setting-background-images-in-jframe) but I had no luck.

The 1st method it gave me I tried and then instead of showing anything it showed nothing at all, no picture no components nothing at all. In case if you need more information I have: 4 JPanels on the bottom of the screen, I also have a border surrounding my window but doesn't show up in the 1st window. I also have borders surrounding my panels too.

So the 1st method I've tried setting it on the content pane, image loads but all of the components are gone.

2nd method I've tried adding it into the content pane but yet again with no luck and I get a panel with no background.

3rd method I've tried is creating a separate class and overriding the paintComponent method and adding an image to the constructor of it then placing this object of the class into the setcontentPane() parameter of the frame. Does not work at all, all I get is a blank frame.

Code I am using for my frame:

```
public class LoginScreen {

JCheckBox remember_User;
JButton login, create_Account, forums, faqs;
Border whiteLine;
JTextField userField;
JFormattedTextField passField;

private void createView() {
    // Created essential details for the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Name of the game");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Defining panels and a constraint on the bottomPanel.
    // More info - Total amt of panels: 5
    // pLogin and pInfo are in the bottomCompPanel and bottomCompPanel is in
    // bottomPanel
    // bottom panel is in pMain
    // Giving panels some attributes like backgrounds and borders
    JPanel pMain = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    pMain.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(3, 3, 6, 3,
            Color.DARK_GRAY));
    frame.getContentPane().add(pMain);

    whiteLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    JPanel pLogin = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pLogin.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    pLogin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
    pLogin.setBorder(whiteLine);

    JPanel pInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pInfo.setBackground(Color.green);
    pInfo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
    pInfo.setBorder(whiteLine);

    JPanel bottomCompPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints bGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    bGBC.gridx = 0;
    bGBC.gridy = 0;
    bGBC.insets = new Insets(0, 20, 0, 0);
    bGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;

    bottomCompPanel.add(pLogin, bGBC);
    bGBC.gridx++;
    bottomCompPanel.add(pInfo, bGBC);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    bottomPanel.add(bottomCompPanel);
    pMain.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    LoginScreen login = new LoginScreen();
    login.createView();
}
```

}

POST UPDATE 2: Here is the code that I've used using @peeskillet's 1st method. It works sort of but it gives me the same results as the 3rd photo, a cut off picture. P.S I add the panels down at the bottom to my JLabel at the end.

```
private void createView() {

    //Created essential details for the frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("Name of the game");
    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("res/Wallpaper.png"));
    background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(background);


    //Defining panels and a constraint on the bottomPanel. 
    //More info - Total amt of panels: 5
    //pLogin and pInfo are in the bottomCompPanel and bottomCompPanel is in bottomPanel
    //bottom panel is in pMain
    //Giving panels some attributes like backgrounds and borders

    whiteLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    JPanel pLogin = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pLogin.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    pLogin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,250));
    pLogin.setBorder(whiteLine);

    JPanel pInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    pInfo.setBackground(Color.green);
    pInfo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,100));
    pInfo.setBorder(whiteLine);

    JPanel bottomCompPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

    GridBagConstraints bGBC = new GridBagConstraints();
    bGBC.gridx = 0;
    bGBC.gridy = 0;
    bGBC.insets = new Insets(0,20,0,0);
    bGBC.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_END;

    bottomCompPanel.add(pLogin, bGBC);
    bGBC.gridx++;
    bottomCompPanel.add(pInfo, bGBC);

    JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    bottomPanel.add(bottomCompPanel);
    background.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: I've tried the thread above you mentioned, none of it methods that it has given me seems to work. I updated the thread with more information incase if that helps.

Comment: Can't seem to find any other method that can be used....

Comment: you have two problems , the first is that you have to re-size the background image based on the frame's width/height , and the second is that based on frame's dimensions you have to render your panels above the background panel (which has the backroung image for full frame) in  the proper position which in your example should be somewhere in the middle

Comment: Ok I have to resize the image sure but I don't understand what you mean by rendering my panels into the middle. I want to keep my panels in that exact location that it is in the example. I deliberately made it like that because I thought it looked nice. Why would I have to position the panels in the middle in there to make it work?

Comment: Your question has not received enough attention because you have not provided a short, self-contained, **runnable** example with a link to your background image and 2 JPanels.

Comment: I am sorry. The code now works now and any placeholder image for the background is fine. Sorry for the error I hadn't realized the code didn't work until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I tried to set the JFrame content pane as a label with an imageicon"

You need to set the layout on the `JLabel`. It will be null be default.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class BackgroundImage {

    private static final String IMG = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEoYs.jpg";

    private void init() throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel background = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(IMG)));
        background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        background.add(loginPanel());
        f.setContentPane(background);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel loginPanel() {
        Border whiteLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        JPanel pLogin = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pLogin.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        pLogin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        pLogin.setBorder(whiteLine);
        return pLogin;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new BackgroundImage().init();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

> "I've tried is to create a subclass of JComponent and Override the paintComponents method then setan object of it as the contentpane"

Should be `paintComponent` (no "s"), but just like with `JLabel`, you need to set the layout. `JComponent` layout is null be default. You also need to give it a preferred size when painting.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class BackgroundImage {

    private static final String IMG = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEoYs.jpg";

    private void init() throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent background = new BackgroundComponent(new ImageIcon(new URL(IMG)));
        background.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        background.add(loginPanel());
        f.setContentPane(background);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel loginPanel() {
        Border whiteLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        JPanel pLogin = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pLogin.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        pLogin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        pLogin.setBorder(whiteLine);
        return pLogin;
    }

    class BackgroundComponent extends JComponent {
        public ImageIcon background;
        public BackgroundComponent(ImageIcon background) {
            this.background = background;
        }
        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(background.getIconWidth(), background.getIconHeight());
        }
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(background.getImage(),
                        0, 0,
                        background.getIconWidth(), 
                        background.getIconHeight(), this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new BackgroundImage().init();
            } catch (Exception ex) {}
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

Using (extending) `JPanel` instead of `JComponent` would be similar except `JPanel` *does* have a default layout which is `FlowLayout`.

---

#### UPDATE

To get your desired layout, you need to play around with the different layout managers. The combination I used is

```
Outer (main panel)     -- BorderLayout
Bottom (bottom panel)  -- BoxLayout inside (south) of outer layout
```

For the BorderLayout, you need to make sure the panel opaque property is set to false, as BorderLayout will stretch the panel and cover the background.

For the BoxLayout, you need to make sure to set the maximum size and the preferred size

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class BackgroundImage {

    private static final String IMG = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/JEoYs.jpg";
    private final Border whiteLine = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);


    private void init() throws Exception {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent background = new BackgroundComponent(new ImageIcon(new URL(IMG)));
        background.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        background.add(bottomPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        f.setContentPane(background);

        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel bottomPanel() {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
        bottomPanel.setLayout(layout);
        bottomPanel.setOpaque(false);
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        bottomPanel.add(loginPanel());
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 0)));
        bottomPanel.add(infoPanel());
        return bottomPanel;
    }

    private JPanel infoPanel() {
        JPanel pInfo = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pInfo.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
        pInfo.setBackground(Color.green);
        pInfo.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        pInfo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        pInfo.setBorder(whiteLine);
        return pInfo;
    }

    private JPanel loginPanel() {
        JPanel pLogin = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        pLogin.setAlignmentY(Component.BOTTOM_ALIGNMENT);
        pLogin.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        pLogin.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        pLogin.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(400, 250));
        pLogin.setBorder(whiteLine);
        return pLogin;
    }

    class BackgroundComponent extends JComponent {

        public ImageIcon background;

        public BackgroundComponent(ImageIcon background) {
            this.background = background;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(background.getIconWidth(), background.getIconHeight());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(background.getImage(),
                    0, 0,
                    background.getIconWidth(),
                    background.getIconHeight(), this);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            try {
                new BackgroundImage().init();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[image]

For more information about using the different layout managers, see

- [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z14ya.png)

Comment: I've tried out the 1st method you gave me, it works but for some odd reason it gives me the same result as the 3rd picture, it cuts the screen in half and only shows half of the image. I know your panel is in the center but mine isn't so maybe that's the problem? I don't want to center my panels but if that's the case I may have to. I updated the post with my code that I use that gave me the result of the 3rd photo.

Comment: Well then you need to see what you are doing differently from my code. All my code work. As for the centering, it is only centered because of the `GridBagLayout` I set. For different layouts, you need to learn the different layout managers.

Comment: I just used instead of a GridBagLayout a border layout. That's all I did and I also did not initialize a url like what you did above. I got the picture from my res folder.

Comment: Most of the backgrounds are connected by the way, the bottomComp Panel adds in the pLogin and pInfo and then there is a bottomPanel that adds in the bottomComp panel and finally the background adds in the bottomCompPanel which basically adds in all of it.

Comment: If all you change in my code was changing the `GridBagLayout` to `BorderLayout`, then you would not get your split image. The blue panel would cover the whole screen

Comment: I updated my post to show what exactly I did. I did not change nothing at all. The only things that changed were the panels that were added.

Comment: Let me just tell you... YOU ARE MY HERO! This worked very well and I can't believe all I had to do was set opaque to false for my gui. Thank you so much for your patience and help. Without you I probably would have never gotten this done :). Thank you again and I really do appreciate your hard work and patience to help me, you made my day and my life a whole lot easier :).

Answer (score 1):

You can try JLayeredPane and setOpaque(boolean) method. 
Code:

```
public class BackgroundImageTest{
    private JFrame frame;

    public BackgroundImageTest() {
        frame = new JFrame("Background Image Frame");

        // set frame properties

        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        panel.setOpaque(false);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Change Background");
        panel.add(btn);

        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                setBackgroundImage(getImage(new File("Wallpaper2.png")));
            }
        });

        JPanel main = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
        main.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        main.add(panel);
        main.setOpaque(false);

        setBackgroundImage(getImage(new File("Wallpaper.png")));

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private Image getImage(File imageFile) {
        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return image;
    }

    private void setBackgroundImage(Image img) {
        if(img == null) return;

        ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel lblBG = new JLabel(ii);
        lblBG.setName("BackgroundImageLabel");

        JLayeredPane layeredPane = frame.getLayeredPane();

        Component[] comps = layeredPane.getComponentsInLayer(new Integer(Integer.MIN_VALUE));
        for (int i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(comps[i].getName());

            if (comps[i] instanceof JLabel && comps[i].getName().equals("BackgroundImageLabel")){
                layeredPane.remove(comps[i]);
                break;
            }
        }

        layeredPane.add(lblBG, new Integer(Integer.MIN_VALUE));
        lblBG.setBounds(0,0,ii.getIconWidth(), ii.getIconHeight());
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried using the methods that you provided for me on the bottom... doesn't work for some reason. It just shows a normal frame without a background. The opaque method does not work at all too :(.